# UPS office property is not updated after incremental sync, only full sync is updating this property

Tags: user-profile-service, profile-sync, ups

I am using sp2010. I have in the ups a property names "Office". This property was here OOTB and is mapped to AD property "physicalDeliveryOfficeName". When I change this AD property and do a incremental sync in UPS this property is not updated in SharePoint. I check this in the UPS by searching for this user. When I do a full sync it is updating very well. What is going wrong with my incremental sync? An incremental sync needs to update userprofiles which have changes?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell, but maybe the account don't have the permission "Replicate Directory Changes" on the Organization Unit (OU) your trying to incrementallt sync in the Active Directory.

Reference: [Rational Guide to implementing SharePoint Server 2010 User Profile Synchronization](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx)

> Incremental Sync: if Active Directory was the directory source, a full synchronization was completed earlier, and an incremental synchronization is being run.
>   The steps performed for incremental sync are exactly the same as full sync, except wherever a sync or import step were performed, it’s now replaced by Delta sync or Delta import, respectively. Only the changes flow through, not everything.

Reference: [How user profile synchronization works in SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spsocial/archive/2010/05/04/conceptual-view-of-how-user-profile-synchronization-works-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

Comment: Also to add to this, if your netbios domain name (Contoso\username) is different from your FQDN (microsoft.com), then you need to perform the Replicate directory changes to the configuration naming context of the domain.